# Gallery grid not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I've run into a problem with the Wordpress theme I'm using. I'm not a dev by any means so please bear with me, I'll try my best to describe the issue as clear as possible.

Basically the grid gallery won't display until I change the size of the browser's window. Upon loading the page, the element seems to be there but images are not visible. They pop into their places right after I make any change to the browser's windows size. Then everything works as intended until you reload the page.

[Here you can see the page right after loading.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JC282.jpg)

[And here right after I used inspect element, which resizes the window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lC9W2.jpg)

[Link](https://michalflorianczyk.pl/archiwa/portfolio/fotograf) to the page if you want to see it yourself.

Is there a way to display this as it should be with custom CSS or JS?

I understand its not a lot to work with, I'll be happy to provide more information if needed.

Comment: The page seems to load correctly on my end. It seems that the photos are so large that they just take a few seconds to load!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about wordpress and certainly i don't know anything about this gallery plugin that you are using, and **this is not a solution, this is a workaround**, so if anyone post an actual solution, you should try to fix this issue.

I've noticed that you, or some plugin has imported jQuery, so we will use it.

```js
(function () {
  function triggerFakeResizeEvent () {
    window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('resize'));
  }
  if (jQuery.isReady) {
    triggerFakeResizeEvent();
  } else {
    jQuery.ready(triggerFakeResizeEvent);
  }
})()
```

If the page is already fully loaded it will trigger a fake resize event, otherwise it will wait until the page loads and then it will trigger such event.

Im not sure how much control you have over placing custom JavaScript in Wordpress, but it is important that this code will be executed after jQuery and your gallery plugin has been loaded.

If you can't do this, or the console says things like `jQuery is not defined`, try placing this instead

```js
  (function (){
    function triggerFakeResizeEvent () {
      window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('resize'));
    }
    triggerFakeResizeEvent()
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', triggerFakeResizeEvent);
  })()
```

Comment: Your workaround solved the problem for now! Dziękuję Ci bardzo. :)

Comment: Prosze bardzo ;)